# How to create permutations of a list in chunks

Tags: java, permutation, traveling-salesman

I'm working on the traveling salesman problem in java. I am using recursion to create all possible route permutations and this works well up to 12 destinations. My program needs to be able to handle 13 destinations and storing factorial 13 permutations (over 6 billion) causes java to throw a heap space error. So my question is this, how can I create these 6 billion permutations in "chunks"? This would also allow me to pass these chunks to various worker threads as they're completed. My current, working recursion code is below.

```
 private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        helper(1, nums, result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void helper(int start, int[] nums, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result){
        if(start==nums.length-1){
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int num: nums){
                list.add(num);
            }
            result.add(list);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=start; i<nums.length; i++){
            swap(nums, i, start);
            helper(start+1, nums, result);
            swap(nums, i, start);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j){
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to calculate only the one permutation each time for processing [this may be useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string) instead of storing all permutations as this consumes lot of space.

Comment: Please post [mre] and include hard-coded test data.

Comment: No for 13 destinations you need just 12! permutations because `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)` has 13 independent cycles, but you need permutions with just one cycle, to complete youre route.